# Maven Spring Boot App Failing to Start from VS Code

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

Attempting to write a Java RESTful API When I run `mvn clean install` I build no problem. When I run `mvn spring-boot run` I get the following runtime error. I have included the `pom.xml` and `classes` that I think are relevant. I also have a service layer and entity class not listed, though I don't think they are the issue. I can add if maybe someone would like to see them as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you in advance.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
```

below is code that I think could potentially be causing the problem:

`pom.xml`

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>Java_API</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

`Main.java`

```
package com.example.myproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(myController.class,args);
    }
}
```

`myController.java`

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class myController {


    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/employee/{id}")
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
        return employeeService.getEmployee(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/employee")
    public void createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        EmployeeService.createEmployee(employee);
    }
}
```

- I have tried only having `starter-web` instead of both `starter-web` and `starter-tomcat`, but it yields the same result. The versioning seems right.
- tried adding `<scope>provided</scope>`, granted I'm not entirely sure what it does.
- A number of other things that may come to me, blanking on everything I have tried. Really stumped on what it does not like.

Comment: You are using the spring boot maven plugin from Spring Boot 3.0.2 where the rest is Spring BOot 2.3.3.. THe versions don't match. Ideally you should have a spring boot starter as parent and don't specify any further versions. You also marked tomcat as provided and thus no servlet container is going to be available. Finally you should use `Main.class` instead of `myController.class` in your main method to launch the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Main.java

change `SpringApplication.run(myController.class,args);`

to
`SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //SpringApplication.run(myController.class,args);
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
```

## pom.xml

you can remove `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>Java_API</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
      <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

package and run

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:run
```

test

```
curl http://localhost:8080/employee/22
```

## I can't get enough information from your question. I change my test code:

### myController.java

```
package com.example.myproject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class myController {
    //@Autowired
    //private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/employee/{id}")
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
        Employee e1=new Employee();
        e1.setId(id);
        e1.setName("Hello World");
        return e1;
        //return employeeService.getEmployee(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/employee")
    public void createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        System.out.println("DEBUG-"+ employee.getId()+"\t"+employee.getName());
        //EmployeeService.createEmployee(employee);
    }
}
```

### Employee.java

```
package com.example.myproject;

public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I use the following code to test on my machine and it can be executed. At the same time, when you change `SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);` back to `SpringApplication.run(myController.class, args) ;`, when executed it throws the same error message as in the question, `Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.`

If there are other error messages generated, it should be part of your `EmployeeService`. You did not provide enough information.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sorry I didn't include the other classes.